# AWS EC2 new instance from image AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to create AMI image based on my current EC2 Linux instance. There are things that bothers me tough, and I didn't find any accurate answer to my questions on the web.

My current EC2 instance has:

- two private interfaces like eth0 and eth0:1
- two elastic IP addresses, each of them points to above ifaces

The answer I'm missing is, will the new instance launched based on this image be created in the same manner? Duplicating somehow my current settings, etc? Is it even a problem if cloned 1:1? Since, that would be more sufficient from the Load Balancing standpoint.

From the other side, it can't be duplicated in the meaning of private IP addressing, cause I wouldn't be able to differentiate them connecting with ssh. Any1 has some experience creating images based on EC2 instances, and can hint me how it looks?

Comment: Ok I have risked a try :) the system looks the same, mapped 1:1. The only difference is the private IP, which can be assigned manually when launching. It's cool.

Answer (score 1):

When launching an instance from an Amazon Machine Image (AMI), the disks will contain an exact copy of the disk at the time that the AMI was created.

However, other attributes might be different when launching a new instance, such as the number of Elastic Network Interfaces and, of course, the IP address will most likely be different. Therefore, you will need to request similar settings from EC2 when then instance is launched.