# EC2 AMI and installed third party software - how does this work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, deprecated, amazon-ami

I've been using a Windows 2008R2 EC2 instance for some time. As of today, it still works. I started working with the AWS API, and I was unable to start my instance using the API, the error message being "not authorized for images", specifically : **An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the RunInstances operation: Not authorized for images: [ami-088dab1e]**

That's when I learned about deprecation.

From what I read, what this means is that the AMI being used is no longer publicly available. When using the API call "describe-images", this image cannot be queried. While it apparently can still be used from the console, the API simply doesn't support it and will not start an instance using that image ID.  On the console, the AMI description reads : *Cannot load details for ami-088dab1e. You may not be permitted to view it.*

I understand how to find a new image and I think I understand how to launch my instance using a new image.  However, I have lots of custom software installed on this instance. So before I try it, I want to know if I will lose that custom software installation if I launch my existing instance with a new AMI.  I'm hoping that my custom software won't change, but I'm skeptical.  I don't want to fire up a brand new version of Windows and start from scratch. Mostly, I don't want to lose what I've already got.

I know this is a basic question, but I've looked all over, and I haven't yet found a straightforward answer.  I was hoping y'all would know.  Thanks.

Comment: Which specific kind of thing is *`not authorized for images`*?  Is it an `ami` or an `aki` or something else?

Comment: Question edited to explain.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's what's confusing about your question... if you were trying to **start** an existing instance, you should not have seen an error mentioning `RunInstances`.  `RunInstances` is for launching **new** instances, not starting stopped ones, and if you are launching a new instance from a vendor AMI, there is no software on it. It's not clear what you were trying to do, because the error message does not match the explanation.

Comment: ah!  Yes, I am making that rookie mistake. It's my 2nd day. :-) I am trying to start an existing image using RunInstances.  You'd think they'd call it LaunchInstances, amirite? Still, the "describe-images" doesn't report on the image I was usings, so maybe I run into the same problem. You've given me a huge push away from the wrong direction, so thanks for that.  I'll try start-instances command and report back. I just finished up the patch maintenance, so that seems like it was a worthwhile effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer here: [AWS EC2 new instance from image AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695660/aws-ec2-new-instance-from-image-ami?rq=1)

> When launching an instance from an Amazon Machine Image (AMI), the disks will contain an exact copy of the disk at the time that the AMI was created.

In other words, if I start a new instance, I'll lose my installed software. WRONG!

Launching != starting.  More editing to come once I get this completely figured out.

So, given that updated Windows images are created and deprecated all the time, and the Windows OS is constantly updated by Microsoft, one must wonder how it is a static Windows image can be used with other software?  It seems like far more trouble than it's worth, if you've got to constantly reinstall your software to keep your Windows system up to date.

Amazon recently came up with a solution for that, here: [Patching Windows](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/windows-ami-patching-and-maintenance-with-amazon-ec2-systems-manager-2/)

I don't know how to do it yet, but this seems like exactly what I need in order to keep Windows up to date, and keep my installed software intact.

Comment: You can also keep Windows instances up to date the same way you keep any Windows machine up to date -- with [Windows Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3067639/how-to-get-an-update-through-windows-update).

Comment: I keep my tax software on the machine.  I only start it when I'm doing returns, then I stop it.  Never terminate. If I did Windows update, are you also saying that the image I use would be updated, and the next time, I'd start from where I left off?  All of a sudden, that seems so intuitive now.. otherwise, how could I keep my installed software. Duh!  I'm pretty new at this, if you can't tell.  Thanks.

Comment: An "image" a.k.a. AMI (Amazon Machine Image) consists of the snapshots and metadata necessary to launch a new instance.  Usually these are OS-only, though you can bake one with software you installed.  If you stop and later start an instance, you don't use an AMI, you just... start the instance.

Comment: I think I need to be a little more careful, a little less ignorant about the nomenclature I use.  You've been a big help, thank you.